# Efficiently Filter Parent Table with Join to Two (or more Children Tables)

Tags: sql-server, performance, index, join

Given the following schema for Microsoft SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
   TenantId int,
   Id int,
   ChildAId int,
   ChildBId int,
);

CREATE TABLE ChildA (
   TenantId int,
   Id int,
);

CREATE TABLE ChildB (
   TenantId int,
   Id int,
);
```

I want to efficiently filter rows from `Parent` based on matching rows from `ChildA` and `ChildB`. We can assume that there are a lot of rows in these tables, and the query needs to execute very frequently and quickly with minimal CPU/memory overhead (no sorting, no hash joins, etc).

The basic query I want to execute is:

```
SELECT
    Parent.Id
FROM Parent
JOIN ChildA
    ON ChildA.TenantId = Parent.TenantId
   AND ChildA.Id = Parent.ChildAId
JOIN ChildB
    ON ChildB.TenantId = Parent.TenantId
   AND ChildB.Id = Parent.ChildBId
WHERE
    Parent.TenantId = @TenantId
```

Thinking like the database engine, the best algorithm for filtering would be a "merge join" as long as we don't need to sort anything.

Assume we have the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX Parent__TenantId__ChildAId__ChildBId ON Parent (TenantId, ChildAId, ChildBId);

CREATE INDEX ChildA__TenantId__Id ON ChildA (TenantId, Id);

CREATE INDEX ChildB__TenantId__Id ON ChildB (TenantId, Id);
```

A merge join between `Parent` and `ChildA` should be possible since the indexes are in the same order. But we can't do a subsequent merge join to `ChildB` because the results from the first join aren't ordered by "ChildBId". It'll either need to sort (not ideal) or use a loop join/hash join.

As a programmer, I know that I could execute *N* merge joins to `ChildB` for each group by "ChildAId", because each group is ordered by "ChildBId" due to the index. But it doesn't seem like SQL Server knows how to do this, or just can't do this. It also might not be ideal, as worst case we need to read over all rows of `ChildB` up to *N* times, maybe not much better than a normal loop join in practice.

Is there any way to index these tables and craft a query (using hints is perfectly acceptable) to force a plan that filters with sorting or using loop/hash joins?

Comment: First, stop looking at this solely from a table/query perspective.  Get rid of the `Id`s.  What are the actual entities & relationships we are modeling?  Context is important.

Comment: Why the aversion to hash joins? They will allow you to look at each row source once using the TenantId filter and join them together. Hashing is very efficient and is only going to be less efficient if the data is already sorted (and even then the different is not worth worrying about). Have you got some real data that you’ve done benchmarks with? Is this query representative of a real query you need to run? How often are you going to run it? How many rows are you going to receive?

Comment: How many rows are in each table? How many times will the query be executed per minute? How fast do you think you need the query to execute?

Comment: If absolute `SELECT` performance is needed, and modification performance is not such a concern, then an indexed view of your above query might be the best solution. Barring that, just leave it up to the server as to which join to use. It's a mathematically simple query, so it shouldn't have much trouble choosing the best option given good indexes and statistics. Note that the second join may not matter much if the results are already much reduced by the first join, so it's primarily a matter of join cardinalities.

Comment: Where are the keys?  These look like 1-1 relationships, which have poor code smell.